# Password is not set error when using com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource with JNDI

Tags: jdbc, jndi, ibm-midrange

i'm trying to make a JDBC connection using com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource with JNDI.
When i debug i notice that when the InitialContext is set up an instance of the datasource is created. And when i get the reference from my code another instance is created, with a copy of an AS400 object (which contains url , user name and connection config).

On the first instance im invoking

```
as400Ds.setPassword("MYPWD");
```

Problem is when the AS400 instance is shared the password is lost, so i get this error

```
Password is not set
```

Comment: Turns out that if you call

    as400ds.setSavePasswordWhenSerialized(true);

on the first instance created the password is shared.

Still, for me, this is not the expected behavior. With any other JDBC driver there´s no need to do anything similar AFAIK.

Any one care to explain the reason behind this?

Is it possible that there is a security vulnerability when calling this method? or with the rest of the jdbc drivers that dont need something equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public void setSavePasswordWhenSerialized(boolean savePassword)
>
> Sets whether to save the password locally with the rest of the properties when this data source object is serialized. If the password is saved, it is up to the application to protect the serialized form of the object because it contains all necessary information to connect to the IBM i system. The default is false. It is a security risk to save the password with the rest of the properties so by default the password is not saved. If the application programmer chooses to accept this risk, set this property to true to force the Toolbox to save the password with the other properties when the data source object is serialized.

[IBM docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDataSource.html?lang=en)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. for some reason i couldn´t find the docs you provided when i posted the question

Comment: I know its been a while - i just stumbled upon it and wrote just in case :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you call

```
as400ds.setSavePasswordWhenSerialized(true);
```

on the first instance created the password is shared.

Still, for me, this is not the expected behavior. With any other JDBC driver there´s no need to do anything similar AFAIK.

Any one care to explain the reason behind this?

Is it possible that there is a security vulnerability when calling this method? or with the rest of the jdbc drivers that dont need something ?